# Translation animation of view when referenced view's width is wrap_content in ConstraintSet animation

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintset

This is the design of xml layout `begin.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            style="@style/DeleteButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:translationZ="-2dp"
            />

    <View
            android:id="@+id/top_layer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bet_slip_remove_item"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/close"
            android:background="@drawable/button_white_radius_10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/top_layer"
            android:contentDescription="@string/close"
            />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/timeout_error"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/top_layer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/top_layer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/top_layer"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It looks something like this:

[image]

There is a `Delete` button hidden behind `top_layer` view.

By clicking on "X" I wish, by using ConstraintSet animations, `top_layer` view to go left with its left part to be outside of the screen and to reveal `Delete` button, to get something like this:

[image]

The problem lies in the fact that `Delete` button has its width set to `wrap_content`, but even if it has the fixed width, how can I set xml layout `end.xml`, to get the desired design on the last picture?

Setting view's position that one part of it is outside of screen puzzles me.

Side note: I use `top_layer` view for two reasons:

1. it hides DeleteButton
2. since all views (X, TextView and presumably others which should be there) should move to the left together, I set their constraints to be relative to `top_layer`'s dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

*Update:* Just realized that you are using animation through *ConstraintSet*. The easiest thing to do is to set up a clone of your delete button (at least some view with the same width) with its end constraint set to the start of the parent layout. This will give you an off-screen widget whose start side is off screen by how far you want to move your other widgets. You can then set new constraints to that left side and apply the transition.

Here is a sample app:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
        cs.clone(layout);
        ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
        transition.setDuration(1000);

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(layout, transition);
        cs.connect(R.id.some_text, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.offScreenView, ConstraintSet.START);
        cs.connect(R.id.bet_slip_remove_item, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.delete, ConstraintSet.START);
        cs.applyTo(layout);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**
This is a little simplified, but it shows the concepts.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/offScreenView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/delete"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/delete"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        android:text="@string/timeout_error"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/delete"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/bet_slip_remove_item"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bet_slip_remove_item"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/delete"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/close" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

---

Animation with the *translationX* property also works:

You can setup an animation of the *translationX* property for each element you need to move to the left. You will also need to determine the width of the "delete" button to know how far to move left.

Add something like this to the startup part of your app - *onCreate()* for an activity:

```
// Top level member variables.
private ObjectAnimator slide1Animator;
private ObjectAnimator slide2Animator;
private ObjectAnimator slide3Animator;   

findViewById(R.id.top_layer).getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            View topLayer = findViewById(R.id.top_layer);
            View someText = findViewById(R.id.some_text);
            View delete = findViewById(R.id.bet_slip_remove_item);
            pixToSlide = -findViewById(R.id.delete).getWidth();
            slide1Animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(topLayer, "translationX", pixToSlide)
                    .setDuration(1000);

            slide2Animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(someText, "translationX", pixToSlide)
                    .setDuration(1000);

            slide3Animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(delete, "translationX", pixToSlide)
                    .setDuration(1000);
        }
    });
```

Then, in a click handler for the "x", do the following:

```
slide1Animator.start();
slide2Animator.start();
slide3Animator.start();
```

This will shift the views off to the left side of the screen and expose the delete button underneath.